# Can I use A-records to create name servers, and a server hostname on one server, but the overall name servers of that domain point to another?

Tags: apache-2.2, nameserver, glue-record

OK - to clarify for those who did not understand the first question:

- LAMP/cPanel Server hostname srv1.xyz.com
- Nameservers used for OTHER domains are ns1.xyz.com and ns2.xyz.com ON THIS SERVER
- I now have a new server which I wish to be called srv2.xyz.com
- I also wish to use the domain www.xyz.com on the NEW server srv2.xyz.com
- Aside from the ns1 and ns2 A-records already in existance pointing at srv1, what additional A-Records do I need to create on the domain xyz.com to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: I have read this three times now and I have absolutely no idea what you want to do and why, and what your problem is. Please reformulate the question so that you describe what your underlying problem is, how you try to solve it and what kind of problem you have with that solution. A little bit of structure for the text would also help, the formatting tools are there for a reason.

Comment: I was going to say as much as SvenW. I am REALLY unclear what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely:

1. Create an A record point at your new server's IP address for `srv2.xyz.com`
2. Create either another A record for `www.xyz.com` pointing at the same IP address or a CNAME pointing `www.xyz.com` to `srv2.xyz.com`?

I don't really get why this is a hard problem, or why you think your NS records need to get involved in this.